# How to create empty working boost::python::dict?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, initialization, boost-python

I parse a C++ project which compiling as `library.so` for python. So I can`t debug it inside Qt creator IDE. For this purpose I created separate project with executable *main()*:

```
int main()
{
    boost::python::dict whiteList;
    whiteList.has_key("blablabla");
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

On release mode program compiling and work incorrectly. But on **debugging mode** program fails in `has_key()` method with error window:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.
Signal name :    SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

Probably the question is: How to correctly create and use *`boost::python::dict`* purely  inside `C++` program without involving python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use the Python C API or Boost Python, you must initialize Python:

```
Py_Initialize();
```

Add that to the top of your `main()` et voila.